# Can't build iOS Cordova app with Firebase on M1 Mac: "Module 'FirebaseFirestore' not found" and "framework not found AppAuth"

Tags: xcode, firebase, cordova, apple-m1, cordova-plugin-firebasex

I'm using Cordova 11.0.0 (cordova-ios 6.2.0) on a brand new Mac mini with an M1 chip, using Xcode 13.2.1, and I can't build my app for the iOS simulator.  I'm trying to use `cordova-plugin-firebasex` 14.0.0 , but I can't build the app either with or without this plugin.  With the plugin, I get `Module 'FirebaseFirestore' not found`, while without it I get `framework not found AppAuth`.  I've searched on both of those errors, as well as on many others I've seen, for the past 3 days; the many solutions I've found and tried either don't work or are not applicable to an M1 machine.  I've reinstalled almost everything, including Xcode, and many things multiple times.  I've tried `pod repo update`, `pod install`, and `pod update` many times.

Other tool versions:

- ruby 3.1.0p0   (installed via homebrew)
- CocoaPods 1.11.2   (installed with above, new version of ruby)
- MacOS 12.2.1

Installing the new ruby and CocoaPods, rather than using MacOS's default versions, did remove a few error messages, and lets me run the `pod` commands without `arch -x86_64` before them.

Interestingly, when the `cordova-plugin-firebasex` plugin is installed, then *every* time I run `pod update`, there are two extra messages in its output:

```
Pre-downloading: `FirebaseFirestore` from `https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git`, tag `8.11.0`
```

and

```
Installing FirebaseFirestore 8.11.0
```

This hints that there's something wrong with the FirebaseFirestore part of Firebase, as if it gets installed incompletely, or as if the plugin is missing some flag in the installation of its FirebaseFirestore component (?).  Note that the line for FirebaseFirestore is different from the others in the Podfile:

```
# DO NOT MODIFY -- auto-generated by Apache Cordova
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'
platform :ios, '11.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'my_app' do
        project 'my_app.xcodeproj'
        pod 'Firebase/Core', '8.11.0'
        pod 'Firebase/Auth', '8.11.0'
        pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '8.11.0'
        pod 'Firebase/Performance', '8.11.0'
        pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig', '8.11.0'
        pod 'Firebase/InAppMessaging', '8.11.0'
        pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :tag => '8.11.0', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git'
        pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics', '8.11.0'
        pod 'Firebase/Functions', '8.11.0'
        pod 'Firebase/Installations', '8.11.0'
        pod 'GoogleSignIn', '6.1.0'
        pod 'GoogleTagManager', '7.3.1'
end
```

Do I understand correctly that `cordova-plugin-firebasex` can be used *either* from the command line (with the `-cli` packages), *or* from Xcode, but not both at the same time?  In any case, I've tried building from the command line too, and that fails when compiling `cordova-plugin-firebasex/FirebasePlugin.m` .

I'm completely new to Firebase and pretty much everything in the Apple world, so all advice is very welcome.  Thanks!

EDIT: A few more things, possible clues:

Under `platforms/iOS/my_app/CordovaLib/`, there is no `Cordova/`, which is apparently supposed to contain `Cordova.h` and `Info.list`.  What could cause this?

Now, after setting `Architectures / Exclude Architectures` to `x86_64`, I get the error message:

`in /Users/me/dev/my_app/platforms/ios/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework/GoogleSymbolUtilities(overload.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/Users/me/dev/my_app/platforms/ios/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework/GoogleSymbolUtilities' for architecture arm64`.

I've also searched on this error message over the past 4 days, but found nothing that has worked.

In `platforms/iOS/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`, `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` is set to `8.0` for these modules (?):  `AppAuth.debug.xcconfig`, `GoogleSymbolUtilities.release.xcconfig`, `GoogleSymbolUtilities.debug.xcconfig`, `AppAuth.release.xcconfig`, `GoogleUtilitiesLegacy.debug.xcconfig`, and `GoogleUtilitiesLegacy.release.xcconfig`.  When building from the command line, a warning says those should be at least `9.0`.  I've tried changing those lines to `9.0` in that file, but the error message is unchanged.  `pod install` plus `pod update` sets those back to `8.0`.

Under `Build Settings / Linking`, I notice that the `Path to Link Map File` is set to a file that doesn't exist:  `build/my_app.build/Debug-iphoneos/.build/-LinkMap--.txt`.  In fact the directory `build/my_app.build/` does not exist.  The filename apparently shows that `PRODUCT_NAME`, `CURRENT_VARIANT`, and `CURRENT_ARCH` are not set.  Is this important?

Thanks for any help at all.  I suspect multiple apps being used here have problems, and solving any one problem would make everything else much easier to diagnose.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but i solve it in this way

1. Remove firebase plugin

> cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebasex

2. Remove ios platform

> cordova platform rm ios

3. upgrade homebrew and all packages

> homebrew upgrade

4. Add ios platform

> cordova platform add ios

5. Install firebasex

> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebasex

6. Build ios (`cordova build ios`) in my case i get this error

> xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active
> developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command
> line tools instance

For solving this i launch this

> sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

([from this](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/569))

6. At this point i run `cordova build ios again` and this time all goes well

I hope this can be usefull

================================

At the end i've found another way, if the before steps does not works.

https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex/issues/735#issuecomment-1140775999

Comment: Thanks!  It all compiles correctly for me when using a physical iPhone, i.e. the problem is just with the simulator, so I'm just testing everything on the physical device.  I'll try your steps to see if they work for me.